# Refiring ready event after AJAX load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to refire the `sss` ready event after the user clicks on `#mail-wrap` which loads in another page with AJAX. However, the event is not refiring. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function sss() {
        $('.slider').sss({
            speed: 5000
        });
    }

    // User event
    $('#mail-wrap').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        sss();
    });

    $('.slider').sss({
        speed: 5000
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other event, the ready event can be triggered explicitly:

```
$(document).trigger('ready');
```

A more elegant solution would be to, instead of using the 'ready' event on the document, put your code in a separate function and call that instead.

**EDIT:** Here is a more complete implementation. The .off() addition is unnecessary and design-wise is pretty inelegant, but declaring a .on() twice should never be necessary either.

```
// Moved this outside of the .ready event
function sss() {
    $('.slider').sss({
        speed: 5000
    });
}
// Moved the rest of our implementation outside as well
function initialize() {

    // Added a .off() to reset the event (shouldn't be necessary, optional)
    $('#mail-wrap').off().on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        sss();
    });

    sss();
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Call it once on document ready, and we can re-initialize anytime we want.
    initialize();

});
```

Comment: I understand the idea but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it. With my existing function (`sss()`), are you saying that I can surround the contents of that function with `$(document).trigger('ready');`? I'm confused because isn't that what it's essentially doing now? When the user clicks on `#mail-wrap`, the `sss()` function fires, no?

Comment: Actually, you don't need to declare functions inside your $(documet).ready, which is something I should have added. I'll show an entire implementation in my edit.